# How to specify OAuth2 scope with spring-social-security SocialAuthenticationFilter?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-social

I'm using Spring Social with Spring Security to authenticate users and automatically create local accounts on my web app. How do I provide the OAuth2 `scope` for authentication?

In the [spring-social-samples](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/blob/master/spring-social-showcase-sec-xml/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/social-security.xml), I don't see where `scope` should go.

```
<bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter"
    c:_0-ref="authenticationManager"
    c:_1-ref="userIdSource"
    c:_2-ref="usersConnectionRepository"
    c:_3-ref="connectionFactoryLocator"
    p:signupUrl="/spring-social-showcase/signup"
    p:rememberMeServices-ref="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0" />

<bean id="socialAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationProvider"
    c:_0-ref="usersConnectionRepository"
    c:_1-ref="socialUsersDetailService" />
```

A specific usecase for `scope` would be to let the user authenticate with Facebook and then get the user's Facebook email (`scope="email"`) for creating a local account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your configuration, you need to specify `scope` as a property of the `FacebookAuthenticationService`. This is the service that handles calls to `auth/facebook`

In XML configuration, instead of:

```
<facebook:config app-id="${facebook.clientId}" app-secret="${facebook.clientSecret}"/>
```

use:

```
<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
    <property name="authenticationServices">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService">
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientId}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientSecret}" />
                <!-- Important: The next property name changed from "scope" to "defaultScope" in 1.1.0.M4 -->
                <property name="scope" value="email" />              
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This works with Spring Social 1.1.0.M3

Comment: I am afraid that this is failing on 1.1.0.M4. Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'scope' of bean class [org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService]: Bean property 'scope' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter

Comment: The property name was changed from scope to defaultScope in 1.1.0.M4. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/1.1.0.M4/spring-social-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/security/provider/OAuth2AuthenticationService.java

Answer (score 3):

You can pass additional `scope` parameter in a connection / signup form. See [example for twitter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/connecting.html#connect-controller-flow-3-scope) from the official documentation:

```html
<form action="<c:url value="/connect/twitter" />" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="publish_stream,offline_access" />
    ...
    <button type="submit"><img src="<c:url value="/resources/social/twitter/signin.png" />"/></button>
</form>
```

It is the same principle for facebook too, just use appropriate scope values.

Be sure that you do not missed this part:

> Facebook access tokens expire after about 2 hours. So, to avoid having
>   to ask your users to re-authorize ever 2 hours, the best way to keep a
>   long-lived access token is to request "offline_access".

Comment: The example above is for `ProviderSignInController`, which uses url `/connect/{provider}`. I'd like to do the same thing with `SocialAuthenticationFilter`, which uses url `/auth/{provider}` or figure out how to combine the two in a single mouse click from the user's perspective.

Comment: Hi @VictorLyuboslavsky , could you find the solution to this yet? I am also using SocialAuthenticationFilter and surprisingly, passing scope as hidden form field works on my localhost but not on production!

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky @shailesh I do not know whether you have found the solution but it is quite simple. Use GET parameter scope and instead of `/auth/facebook` use `auth/facebook?scope=email`.